# Detecting a rectangle drawing on corners of a PDF Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, drawing

Currently i have this method that draws a rectangle on the top left corner of the page. I wanted to create another method that will search for a rectangle drawing in any of the four corners of my scanned document. 
  How can i go about writing a method that will check each corner for a rectangle drawing based what i created for drawing the rectangle.

```
static void AddQRTag(PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics gfx, int xPosition, int yPosition, string QRdata, string HRdata)
    {
        gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.White, xPosition, yPosition, xPosition + 55, yPosition + 85);

        PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage xImage =
            PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(BuildQR(QRdata.ToUpper(), 3,
                                            QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.ALPHA_NUMERIC, 2, QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.M));
        gfx.DrawImage(xImage, xPosition + 5, yPosition + 5, xImage.PixelWidth * .8, xImage.PixelWidth * .8);


        //XFont font = new XFont("OCR B", 10, XFontStyle.Bold);
        XFont font = new XFont("OCR B", 6);
        XTextFormatter tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);
        tf.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Left;

        //XStringFormat format = new XStringFormat();
        //format.Alignment = XStringAlignment.Near;
        XRect layout = new XRect(xPosition + 5, yPosition + 55, 55, 30);
        tf.DrawString(HRdata.ToUpper(), font, XBrushes.Black, layout, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
        //gfx.DrawString(HRdata, font, XBrushes.Black,layout,format);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to use image processing technique to find the rectangle ?

Comment: @OopsUser I'm not sure what would be the most efficient. I was reading about using itextSharp but i am not sure what is the best way that will work. whether finding images in all four corners of a page is better or checking one corner and rotating the document until an image (bitmap) will be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many techniques how to find images inside a PDF file using 3rd party pdf reader API.
But assuming you can't find any method that does it, and assuming you can get read the pdf file and convert them to simple images you can find your rectangle quite easily using image processing techniques.

The simplest (and robust) thing is to look for your rectangle using a simple Correlator, if you don't know the dimensions of the square you can run the correlator sevral times with different rectangles.

If you need high performance there are other solutions (if this is the case just write a comment and i will point you to another direction)

Comment: i need high performance can you redirect me towards that solution!